# Use swedish format in datetime2

Tags: datetime, datetime2, date

I'm trying to use swedish date format by when using the package datetime2. I have found the following link
**https://www.ctan.org/pkg/datetime2-swedish**
but I don't understand how to call for this one. Could anyone help me? This is what I am trying to do:

```
\documentclass[paper=a4,fontsize=11pt]{article} 
\usepackage{datetime2}

\begin{document}   
\begin{minipage}{1\textwidth}
\begin{flushright}
\Large{ \textbf{ Joe Biden }}
\noindent

\hfill \today
\end{flushright}
\end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

I want this to write e.g. 4e november 2016

*As can be seen in the answers and comments this was a problem that was due to a temp.cls - file that was used in a template that I used. Although it has answers on questions when not using this as well.*

Thanks!

Comment: You need to give us more information, among others a full minimal example. I;ve never heard of a document class named `temp`

Comment: I see. I got this from a template when making a resumé.. I'll try to edit the question to create a minimal example, although I am not entirely sure how to do that. :) Just wait a second.

Comment: Could the temp document class come from that it is KOMA-article class? If so, how do you do to use KOMA in a new document? I'm using overleaf

Comment: For now in our tests just use the normal `article` class instead of `temp`. It is a lot easier to make examples fro others when you use a setup that others can understand. Also `datetime2-swedish` is not a latex package, it is a configuration for `datetime2`, it is used when `datetime2` detects that it needs to use  swedish lanuage, for example like in my MWE

Comment: Ah, ok.. I have found the solution: the "temp" comes from a .cls file that is added to the template that I used. And when I'm trying to use the "article"-class other commands stops working, such as the one called "\MyName". However, when I'm using the temp-class the other answer you made does not work. Does this mean I have to chose one or another? 
So you mean the swedsih is "baked in to" the datetime2-package when I use it? If so, how do I "call" it?

Comment: In my example, the `swedish` option ends up being seen by both `babel` and `datetime2`, thus `dateime2` will use its swedish setup. Again we do not know what the `temp` class is! It is not on my system. So with do not know what sort of configurations it might be doing. Please make sure your examples use something others can replicate.

Comment: It is now replicable.. I think? Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The comments on @daleif's answer have become a little convoluted, so it's probably easier if I try to summarise it here as an extension to the other answer.

LaTeX's default format of `\today` is the US style in the form "November 4, 2016". For example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
\today
\end{document}
```

The `babel` package loaded with the option `swedish` redefines `\today` to use the Swedish form "4 november 2016":

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[swedish]{babel}

\begin{document}
\today
\end{document}
```

However, you can't customise this if you want to make some slight modifications (such as have "4e" instead of just "4") and there's also no provision for formatting a specific date. The `datetime2` package provides this extra functionality, but it needs to know what language you're using in your document. Luckily, `datetime2` loads the `tracklang` package which can find out whether `babel` or `polyglossia` or whatever has been used, and it can tell `datetime2` what language(s) you've already requested.

So you can just do:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[swedish]{babel}
\usepackage[useregional=text]{datetime2}

\begin{document}
\today
\end{document}
```

Which produces "4 november 2016" (or you can `useregional=numeric` to get a numeric date in your regional format). Thanks to the `tracklang` package, `datetime2` knows that it needs to load `datetime2-swedish.ldf`, which provides the Swedish date styles (`swedish` and `swedish-numeric`). It's this `datetime2-swedish.ldf` file that provides the command `\DTMswedishordinal` which formats the ordinal part of the `swedish` textual date style.

This can be redefined. For example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[swedish]{babel}
\usepackage[useregional=text]{datetime2}

\renewcommand*{\DTMswedishordinal}[1]{\number#1e}

\begin{document}
\today
\end{document}
```

This produces "4e november 2016".

Other variations include specifying the language as a document class option:

```
\documentclass[swedish]{article}

\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage[useregional=text]{datetime2}

\renewcommand*{\DTMswedishordinal}[1]{\number#1e}

\begin{document}

\today

\end{document}
```

In fact, `datetime2` can be used without `babel`. For example

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[swedish]{datetime2}

\renewcommand*{\DTMswedishordinal}[1]{\number#1e}

\begin{document}

\today

\end{document}
```

Things that can go wrong:

- The package loading is in the wrong order. If `babel` is loaded after `datetime2` instead of before, it's too late for `datetime2` to override `babel`'s date hook. It's also too late to pick up the required language unless it's been passed as a document class option or directly to `datetime2`.
- The class or another package might try redefining `\today` at the start of the document. For example, the following mimics a class that does this:

  ```
  \AtBeginDocument{\def\today{\ifcase\month\or January\or February\or March\or
  April\or May\or June\or July\or August\or September\or October\or
  November\or December\fi \space \number \day, \number \year}}

  \documentclass{article}

  \usepackage[swedish]{babel}
  \usepackage[useregional=text]{datetime2}

  \renewcommand*{\DTMswedishordinal}[1]{\number#1e}

  \begin{document}
  \today
  \end{document}
  ```

  This now produces "November 4, 2016" because of the redefinition in `\AtBeginDocument`.

There's also the possibility that another package loaded after `datetime2` does something similar. To provide a way to counteract this, `datetime2` provides `\DTMtoday` (new to version 1.4) which is `datetime2`'s version of `\today`. You can use it directly or redefine `\today` at the beginning of the document:

```
\AtBeginDocument{\def\today{\ifcase\month\or January\or February\or March\or
April\or May\or June\or July\or August\or September\or October\or
November\or December\fi \space \number \day, \number \year}}

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[swedish]{babel}
\usepackage[useregional=text]{datetime2}

\renewcommand*{\DTMswedishordinal}[1]{\number#1e}

\begin{document}
\DTMtoday
\end{document}
```

This produces "4e november 2016", even though `\today` is back to the original US style. Alternatively:

```
\AtBeginDocument{\def\today{\ifcase\month\or January\or February\or March\or
April\or May\or June\or July\or August\or September\or October\or
November\or December\fi \space \number \day, \number \year}}

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[swedish]{babel}
\usepackage[useregional=text]{datetime2}

\renewcommand*{\DTMswedishordinal}[1]{\number#1e}

\begin{document}
\let\today\DTMtoday

\today
\end{document}
```

If you have an old version of `datetime2` that doesn't recognise `\DTMtoday`, then you can save and restore `datetime2`'s version of `\today` like this:

```
\AtBeginDocument{\def\today{\ifcase\month\or January\or February\or March\or
April\or May\or June\or July\or August\or September\or October\or
November\or December\fi \space \number \day, \number \year}}

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[swedish]{babel}
\usepackage[useregional=text]{datetime2}
\let\dtmtoday\today

\renewcommand*{\DTMswedishordinal}[1]{\number#1e}

\begin{document}
\let\today\dtmtoday

\today
\end{document}
```

It turns out the problem is because your class file `temp.cls` is loading `babel` with `english`. This means that the main document language is English not Swedish so you effectively have a situation analogous to:

```
\documentclass[swedish]{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\begin{document}
\today
\end{document}
```

This sets the main language to `english` with `swedish` as an auxiliary language. You can override this by inserting the following line before the document class is loaded:

```
\PassOptionsToPackage{main=swedish}{babel}
```

This will ensure that `babel` recognises that `swedish` is the main document language.

Comment: Wow, this is such an extensive and impressive answer that it must be the right one. Although it still doesn't work. It must be something with the temp-file that does it. I don't know if this is allowed, but here is a link for the project on overleaf:
https://www.overleaf.com/6883177jyrmgbgwbcqn#/23496337/
THANK YOU for the amazing answer!

Comment: @MIKAELB Your `temp` class loads `babel` with `english`, which is why the date is using the US format. If you change `english` to `swedish` in your `temp.cls` file that should fix the problem.

Comment: Thank you! I see. How do you do to make changes in teh temp.cls-file?

Comment: @MIKAELB It looks like the class file can't be edited. I've modified my answer.

Comment: Wow, it works now. I had sort of given up the hope of this. THANK YOU! Does this last command (\PassOptionsToPackage) force swedish to be the main language independent of what you say after? I.e does it overrule all other language-commands? Thanks again!

Comment: @MIKAELB Yes, it should set `swedish` as the main language. Fortunately the class doesn't use the `main` key  when loading `babel` so `english` will become a secondary language setting. If it had used this key, then that would probably cause a problem, so it's something to watch out for.

Comment: Aha, I see. Thanks! One more question: how do you find all of the info about the cls-file and is it bpossible to download it to your computter from the template somehow, so that I don't have to import it from the old projects every time?

Comment: @MIKAELB If you click on the "Project" button in Overleaf (along the top bar above the code) it should open a side panel where there should be a "Download as zip". That should download all the project files to your computer.

Answer (score 2):

Do you really write it as `4e november` in Sweden, in DK we use `4. november`

Here is an example that works, but does not give you quite the correct output.

```
 \documentclass[a4paper,swedish]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage[useregional=text]{datetime2}

\begin{document}   
 \today

\end{document}
```

Comment: Hmm, you could write:
4 november 2016 (no period)
Although I do not get this one to work either... Not with my document

Comment: @MIKAELB you'll probably need to do your own definition then. `datetime2` should allow you to do that (see the manual), most of Nicolas stuff are highly configurable.

Comment: I see. Could you explain how you do that? I'm fairly new to the latex concept..

Comment: @MIKAELB nope, I don't use the package (and have other things to do), but you should be able to work your way through it via the manual and by looking up datetime questions here (you can usually just googl "latex datetime" and you'll get questions from here.

Comment: `babel`, `polyglossia` and `datetime2` all produce simply "4 november 2016" with the `swedish` language option. To customise `datetime2-swedish` you can just redefine `\DTMswedishordinal`. For example `\renewcommand{\DTMswedishordinal}[1]{\number#1e}` (or use `\ifcase` if the suffix varies according to the number).

Comment: @daleif - I understand, I'll try to look it up. Thanks!

Comment: @NicolaTalbot - I tried to enter this \renewcommand(...) after my "\usepackage{datetime2}" but where was an error. Also tried with "\usepackage{datetime2-swedish}" but no luck. Is there something I don't understand in how to insert this in the text? Thanks! 
UPDATE: I have tried it in the document class "article" in which it works. In other words, it is probably in the formatting of temp the problem is.

Comment: @MIKAELB The `datetime2-swedish.ldf` file is loaded implicitly by `datetime2` if it detects the `swedish` language option. The `swedish` option can be in the document class with `\usepackage[useregional]{datetime2}` (as in @daleif's MWE) but only if the document class uses the standard `\DeclareOption` method of defining options. Since your `temp` class options seem to be using a key=value interface you may have to use `\usepackage[swedish]{datetime2}` (or `\usepackage[swedish]{babel}\usepackage[useregional]{datetime2}` if you're using `babel`) instead.

Comment: I see, although I don't understand everything of that you said I think I get it. And actually I with the help of defining it as swedish made it to write it in text instead. The problem is, however, that it is written as "November 4, 2016" and not "4e november, 2016" which is the proper, swedish way. This even though I'm using the command
 \renewcommand{\DTMswedishordinal}[1]{\number#1e}, which works when in article-mode.

Comment: @MIKAELB It's possible that your class file is redefining `\today` at the start of the document. What happens if you use `\DTMtoday` instead of `\today`?

Comment: @NicolaTalbot Sorry for not responding, been without computer for the weekend. When I wrot \DTMtoday it says it's an undefined control sequence.

Comment: @MIKAELB It sounds like your version of `datetime2` is too old to recognise that command. I'll edit my answer.